# execute done callback of jquery $.when() once (in backbone-js app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'm looking for a way to "unbind" jQuery's `$.when()` after the `.done()` callback has been executed a single time, analogous to using jQuery's `.one()` instead of `.on()` for a single event. The reason why I am using deferred objects instead of events in this circumstance is because I need to wait for multiple asynchronous processes to complete before the callback can be executed.

To go into more detail, I'm working on a backbone application where I have a model and view for each page. The sequence of displaying a new page looks something like this:

1. view for the incoming page (call it page A) is told to render
2. `$.when()` is used by page A to wait for asynchronous processes (3, 4 & 5) to resolve
3. data for page A is loaded from the server, populating the model
4. images in page A's model are preloaded
5. the previous page, page B, finishes closing (animation is complete)
6. page A is rendered

This works fine in a hypothetical scenario where each page is only visited once by a user. However, pages are obviously subject to repeat visits, which means that when page B is opened and closed again after the user navigates elsewhere on the website, the deferred object related to the completion of it's `.close()` method is resolved once more, executing the code block of the `.done()` callback in page A's `.render()` method, which is not good.

Ideally, the `$.when().done()` code block would be "unbound" as soon as it is executed once, or in the `.close()` method of each page, just as many other event listeners are unbound.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, so maybe there as alternative method to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Maybe their is a path that ditches deferreds and listens for multiple events to fire?

Thanks.

Comment: not 100% clear what issues are...would being able to create an array of defffereds and using `$.when` on the array if it has length help?

Comment: here's example of what I'm talking about http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/qR4yH/ It's a series of AJAX calls, unknown number of them but final content is dependent on all calls completed

Comment: I understand that you can can implement `$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferreds)` in order to wait for a list of promises to complete, but I want to be able to unbind the `$.when` once done, or, alternatively, change the contents of the arrayOfDeferreds argument the next time the page is visited so that it waits for a new list of deferreds to resolve (and is no longer concerned with the old list). This doesn't work because `$.when.apply` isn't keeping the array as a reference but simply applying its contents as individual arguments.

Comment: was just thinking the array could change next time page loads... or if it's empty don't call $.when

Answer (score 0):

Internally jQuery uses "callbacks" queues, in a number of its methods, to manage the addition/deletion/firing of multiple functions (eg. event handlers).

The constructor for these queues is exposed as `$.Callbacks(flags)`. The flags, 'once', 'memory', 'unique' and 'stopOnFalse' can be exploited to control the detailed behaviour of the queue when fired. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/).

I'm not sure what the nature of 'visit' and 'repeat visit' is but assume there's a persistence of javascript state, otherwise you wouldn't have a problem. I think you need something like this :

```
//First let's assume you have three promises, corresponding to your steps 3,4,5
var promiseA = .....;
var promiseB = .....;
var promiseC = .....;

//Then you need one or more worker functions
function myFunction() {
    //do whatever is necessary when promises A,B,C are all resolved.
}

//Create a Callbacks queue with the 'once' flag
var callbacks = $.Callbacks('once');//'once' ensures the callback list can only be fired once.
callbacks.add(myFunction);
//add further callback functions here if necessary.

//Now the glue that puts it all together.
$.when(promiseA, promiseB, promiseC).done(callbacks.fire);

//Or, if you need to pass any paramters to the callback function:
$.when(promiseA, promiseB, promiseC).done(function() {
    callbacks.fire(...);
});
```